# Django password reset issue

Tags: python, django, django-rest-auth

I saw a tutorial and I implemented a password resetter through email. The email sending part works fine and I get the email after clicking it I get redirected to reset password page. But after I give the new password and click Submit it gets redirected to the login page but the password is not getting reset.

urls.py

```
    path('password-reset/',auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='password_reset.html'),name='password_reset'),
    path('password-reset/done/',auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_done.html'),name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_confirm.html'),name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password-reset-complete/',auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_complete.html'),name='password_reset_complete'),
```

password_reset_confirm.py

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block head_block %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'index.css' %}">
{% endblock head_block %}

{% block body_block %}
{% csrf_token %}
<form method="post" action="{% url 'reg_sign_in_out:user_login' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="password" name="" id="">
    <input type="submit" value="Reset">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Any idea where the problem is?

Comment: i think you need to specify the `action` for the form, so the url where should the form be posted

Comment: I redirected it to the login page instead of the password_reset_done page but the problem is that I'm not able to change the password. It is stuck on the same password.

Comment: what is your form action on `password_reset_complete.html` template?

Comment: Are you saving the reset password in the view?

Comment: Yes. It was a redirecting issue. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you have to put in your form the action of your post, for example if you have to go to the password-reset/done/ URL, you have to add

```
<form method="post" action="password-reset/done/" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="password" name="" id="">
    <input type="submit" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Because if you don't put the action, it will redirect to the same page

Comment: i hope it will help you

Comment: I redirected it to the login page instead of the password_reset_done page but the problem is that I'm not able to change the password. It is stuck on the same password.

Comment: maybe you have to specify a name to your input, and then extract in your backend with this name with request.POST["name_of_your_input"]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a redirecting issue. Its fixed.